# IP Address Control C++ ASSERT(::IsWindow(m_hWnd)) error

Tags: c++, mfc

I am trying to get an IP address from an IP Address Control in MFC C++. But it is returning an error `ASSERT(::IsWindow(m_hWnd)); return (int) ::SendMessage(m_hWnd, IPM_GETADDRESS, 0, (LPARAM) &dwAddress); }`

Here is the code that I did. The error is generated in this line `Dlg.m_IPAdd.GetAddress(IP2);`

```
BOOL CProxyCardSimulatorDlg::OnInitDialog()
{
CLogin Dlg;
bool isDbConnected;

Dlg.DoModal();

CDialog::OnInitDialog();

// Add "About..." menu item to system menu.

// IDM_ABOUTBOX must be in the system command range.
ASSERT((IDM_ABOUTBOX & 0xFFF0) == IDM_ABOUTBOX);
ASSERT(IDM_ABOUTBOX < 0xF000);

CMenu* pSysMenu = GetSystemMenu(FALSE);
if (pSysMenu != NULL)
{
    CString strAboutMenu;
    strAboutMenu.LoadString(IDS_ABOUTBOX);
    if (!strAboutMenu.IsEmpty())
    {
        pSysMenu->AppendMenu(MF_SEPARATOR);
        pSysMenu->AppendMenu(MF_STRING, IDM_ABOUTBOX, strAboutMenu);
    }
}

// Set the icon for this dialog.  The framework does this automatically
//  when the application's main window is not a dialog
SetIcon(m_hIcon, TRUE);         // Set big icon
SetIcon(m_hIcon, FALSE);        // Set small icon

// TODO: Add extra initialization here

CRect rect;
ConsoleLog.GetClientRect(&rect);

ConsoleLog.InsertColumn(0, _T(" "), LVCFMT_LEFT, rect.Width());

LONG style = ::GetWindowLong(m_IDEnter.m_hWnd, GWL_STYLE);
style |= ES_NUMBER;
::SetWindowLong(m_IDEnter.m_hWnd, GWL_STYLE, style); 

m_IDEnter.SetLimitText(6);

DWORD IP2;

Dlg.m_IPAdd.GetAddress(IP2);  // ERROR HERE

if(true == serverConnect(IP))
{
    addData(ConsoleLog,rec,0,9);
}

return TRUE;  // return TRUE  unless you set the focus to a control
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that the IP address control is on your `CLogin` dialog, that's where you need to call `GetAddress`.

So, override `CLogin::OnOK()` and call `m_IPAdd.GetAddress` there to get the IP address into a `CLogin` member variable. Then you can access that member variable from your enclosing dialog.

The reason it's failing is that by the time you try to access the control from the enclosing dialog, the IP address control on the `CLogin` dialog has already been destroyed. By putting the contents into a `CLogin` member variable, you can still access it.